# Enlazar amigos con spring

Tags: spring

Estoy intentando enlazar grupos de amigos, por ejemplo el usuario A puede tener varios amigos, es decir que cada usuario tiene una lista de amigos.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Friends")
public class Friends implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "idFriend")
    private long idFriend;


    public Friends() {

    }
}
```

Pero mi clase User tiene amigos, estoy creando ciclos? esta bien esto?

```
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany
    private Friends friends;
```

Estoy intentando enlazar mediante los `id` del usuario con el `id` del amigo.

Como creo una segunda llave que sea el id del amigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar relaciones entre tablas, para ello puedes usar la relación de uno a muchos, por la razón que un usuario puede tener muchos amigos.

```
@OneToMany
private User userFriend;
```